# Using SED on MAC (zsh) to get first jpg after marker string

Tags: sed

Please Note: **I found other gnu implementations of this, but they don't seem to work on a mac.  This question is specifically for MacOS running zsh**

I'm trying to pipe some output into SED and use it to find the first jpg after a marker string.

Here is my sample .sh file:

```
Phrase="where is \“frankenstien\" tonight.jpg with my hamburger tomorrow.jpg"
echo $Phrase | sed 's/.*\frankenstien" \(.*\)jpg/\1/'
```

The marker string is “frankenstien" (WITH quotes).  I would like the output to be:

```
tonight.jpg
```

But instead its

```
tonight.jpg with my hamburger tomorrow.
```

So obviously the sequence passed to SED is wrong, how should I write it so that it stops after the first jpg AND includes the ".jpg" in it?  I found many examples online of similar things but they did not work for MAC running zsh.  Can the same code work on macs running bash?  If you only get it to work on bash that might be good enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Your regex is just wrong... `But instead its` sure it is - that's why match `tonight.jpg` and remove the rest. `Can the same code work on macs running bash?` Unless you show what you've found and what did not work, it's hard to guess where from your confusion comes from.

Comment: Also note that you have a unicode double quote `“` in your variable. That's not quite the same as standard quotes `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first jpg, is immediately following the `frankenstien` string (marker), then you can modify your regex to do below. The following should work on any POSIX compliant `sed` as it does not involve any constructs from the GNU version

```
sed 's/.*\"frankenstien\" \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

The above regex will capture the string after the marker string and up to the subsequent space following the required string and ignore the rest.

P.S. Note that the shell versions don't play a role in how your regex string is interpreted by your `sed` installed. Remember `sed` is a binary on its own and comes shipped with your native distro (GNU on Linux and BSD on MacOS). There are few features supported in one and not in the other ( GNU vs *BSD ), but as such the native shell should not come into the picture here. E.g. In MacOS, with a default shell say `zsh`, you can have both BSD `sed` (shipped default) and GNU version (installable using homebrew).

Answer (score 1):

> how should I write it so that it stops after the first jpg AND includes the ".jpg" in it?

Match up until a space.

```
sed 's/.*frankenstien" \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' <<<"$Phrase"
```

Handle tab also:

```
sed 's/.*frankenstien" \([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]].*/\1/' <<<"$Phrase"
```